# Is Phar::webPhar() only used with front controllers?

Tags: php, phar

Is there any reason to use Phar::webPhar(), if you are not accessing the Phar directly in the browser as the front controller to a php web app?

There are two other functions which require Phar::webPhar

- void Phar::mungServer
- Phar::interceptFileFuncs()

Is there any benefit to these functions outside the case of a phar as a front controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `Phar::mungServer()` is really only used in association with `Phar::webPhar()`, but there is no reason to limit the use of `Phar::interceptFileFuncs()` to Phar's using a webPhar stub.  It is just as valid to enable this in a `Phar::mapPhar()` container.